# Imprimiendo array de longitud cero: resultado inesperado

Tags: c

estoy empezando con c y tengo una duda con este código, ¿por que cuando compilo y ejecuto me imprime "abcdefg" en vez de una cadena nula? si le mando al printf desti, me devuelve abcdefg y me estoy volviendo loco. gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    source[8] = "abcdefg";
    char    desti[0];

    printf("%s\n", desti);
    return (0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede considerarse un comportamiento "indeterminado", pues el formato `"%s"` espera una cadena que al final tenga un terminador nulo, por lo que el array `desti` tendría que tener como mínimo un elemento para guardar ese terminador. Es decir, debería ser:

```
char desti[1] = "";
```

Un array de tamaño 0 no está permitido, por lo que podría pasar cualquier cosa. Sin embargo, puestos a elucubrar, podría encontrarse una explicación a lo que has visto.

En tu caso, según cómo se comporte el compilador, podemos entender lo que sucede en la forma siguiente:

- La declaración `char source[8];` reserva espacio en la pila para 8 bytes (pues un `char` es de tamaño byte). Digamos que la pila comienza en la dirección `0xf0004000` por poner un número. Entonces la variable `source` ocuparía desde la dirección `0xf0004000` hasta la `0xf0004007` (8 bytes).
- La asignación `="abcdefg"` en la misma línea en que esa variable es declarada, inicializa los 8 bytes en cuestión con las letras de la cadena. Es decir, en `0xf0004000` irá la primera letra (`'a'`). En la dirección siguiente (`0xf0004001`) iría la siguiente, etc. La cadena "abcdefg" tiene siete letras, pero las cadenas siempre almacenan un byte adicional de valor 0 que actúa como terminador, indicando que la cadena no tiene más letras (observa que el terminador es un byte de valor 0, no un carácter de valor `'0'`)

La situación en memoria sería esta:

[image: Cadena]

- Seguidamente declaras la variable `dest`. Si los datos se estuvieran almacenando en el segmento de datos del programa, esta variable iría a la siguiente dirección disponible tras las ocupadas por `source`, es decir, la dirección 0xf0004008. Sin embargo, ya que las variables locales no se almacenan en la zona de datos sino en la zona de pila, generalmente lo hacen en orden inverso a como han sido declaradas. Así que la "siguiente" zona libre tras la zona ocupada 0xf0004000-0xf0004007 es en realidad la que está detrás, es decir, la que termina en 0xf0003fff.
- La variable `dest` ocupa cero bytes (debido a que la declaras con espacio para 0 bytes), por lo que ocuparía desde las direcciones `0xf0003fff` hasta la `0xf0004000` (excluyendo esta última, que ya pertenece a la variable `source`.

Es decir la situación en memoria sería:

[image: Dos]

No sabemos qué hay en la dirección `0xf0003fff` porque no has inicializado esta variable (y no puede inicializarse porque tiene tamaño cero). De hecho, el compilador podría decidir directamente poner esa variable en la dirección 0xf0004000 por tener la variable tamaño cero (y posiblemente sea eso lo que ocurre en tu compilador).

De este modo, al hacer `printf("%s\n", source)` la función recibe la dirección 0xf0004000 y se pone a mostrar las letras que encuentre en esa dirección hasta encontrar el byte 0 que marca el final.

Seguidamente `printf("%s\n", dest)` recibe la dirección de la variable `dest` y también escribirá los caracteres que allí encuentre hasta llegar al byte 0 que le marque el final. Por tanto puede pasar que:

- Según el compilador, puede que la variable `dest` comience también en 0xf0004000, y por tanto imprimiría exactamente lo mismo.
- O puede que `dest`  comience en 0xf0003fff, en cuyo caso mostraría el primer byte cuyo valor desconocemos (el ? de la figura). Si ese byte fuese 0, ahí terminaría la impresión y verías una cadena vacía, pero si no, mostraría ese byte *y todo lo que haya después*, por tanto la misma cadena de antes.
- Es posible que ese primer byte (casualmente) corresponda a un carácter no visible, por lo que aparentemente verías también lo mismo que en el primer caso.

Comment: Normalmente me gustan tus respuestas ... pero esta es mera especulación. Una vez que entramos en *comportamientos indefinidos* ... no hay mucho mas que hablar. No tenemos ni idea de lo que realmente hace el compilador, salvo que estudiemos el ensamblador generado.

Comment: @Trauma Estoy de acuerdo en que, al ser comportamiento indefinido, el estándar no especifica qué debe hacer el compilador. Pero eso no implica que el resultado sea _aleatorio_ por completo, sino que cada compilador puede implementarlo como quiera. En concreto el almacenamiento de datos en la pila en orden inverso a la declaración es lo más habitual, y dado esto, la explicación proporcionada no es tan arbitraria. Esta explicación no intenta aclarar qué hará _cualquier_ compilador (no es posible eso), sino qué podría estar haciendo su compilador, dada la salida observada

Comment: Además, había hecho algunas pruebas con gcc en OSX y Linux antes de publicar la respuesta, volcando las direcciones de memoria de las variables y sus contenidos, para ratificar que no estuviera diciendo ninguna barbaridad. En ambos casos encontré lo descrito con respecto a las direcciones (el array de tamaño 0 estaba 1 byte por delante del otro), si bien en ambos casos ese array contenía un 0, que hacía que al imprimir `desti` saliera la cadena vacía, por lo que no pude replicar el comportamiento descrito por el usuario.

Comment: gran explicación, entiendo el fallo, empezar con Arrays es encontrarte este tipo de problemas. entiendo que para iniciar una cadena de caracteres al menos tiene que contener el caracter de final de cadena '\0' y este ocupa al menos 1byte.

Answer (score 3):

Los *array* de longitud `0` **están prohibidos** por el estandar, tanto en C como en C++.

De hecho, si intentamos compilar tu programa, obtenemos:

> warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array 'desti'

en traducción libre:

> *aviso*: El estandar ISO C prohibe los array de longitud zero.

Así pues, estas incurriendo en un *comportamiento indefinido*: en ningún sitio está especificado lo que el programa debe hacer en ese caso: el resultado puede ser ... cualquier cosa.